# Blazemeter Chrome Extension Resizing Frame

Tags: blazemeter

I am trying to record actions in the Travel Studio application using Blazemeter to create test cases.  However, when the Blazemeter extension is active in Chrome, it resizes the frames to where the application is pretty much unusable.  Has anyone had this issue with Blazemeter? Any recommendations on how to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to answer the question.
What is "Travel Studio application"? Is it a web site? Can you share the link?
What "it resizes the frames" mean? You have full screen tabs in Chrome and after you start the recording using Blazemeter Chrome extension Chrome tabs getting resized?

The only thing I can tell having the provided input, is that Blazemeter extension records the size of a tab you are recording (the inner dimensions). Then, if you will replay your recording, it will resize the tab according the dimensions you had upon recording. You can change the dimensions of a tab manually in the editor:

[image][image]